# t-sql 2 queries one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is performing two different queries. When the stored procedure is complete I see both result sets. Is there a way to suppress the first result set, and only have the second one display without combining the information?

```
select info 
from table 
where (select * from othertable)
```

This statement causes me to end up with two different result sets. I want to suppress the results from the "othertable" query.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is the first result used at all? If so, how? If not, why use a `SELECT`? Couldn't you just leave the first statement out altogether? Are you maybe looking for a subquery instead (`SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IN (SELECT column FROM othertable)`)? What's your actual problem?

Comment: @JeroenMostert The first result is being inserted into a table. I'm currently using a subquery to filter results dynamically using a split function. What happens when I run it from mgmt. studio I get the results from othertable first, and then I get the bulk data (data I need to insert) second. This information is using a SSRS report and it attempts to use the information from "othertable" instead of the main "table"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note: This is the answer, but not the answer. While going over @Jeroen's response I decided to go into my sproc and include more information in the original post. Upon doing that I came across a "stray" select statement I was using in conjunction with print for debugging purposes. I commented out that line and the additional result set went away. Problem solved! Thank you @Jeoroen!!